# How to insert initial data using sequelize migrations/seeds?

Tags: node.js, express, migration, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create my initial migration to populate the test database but I can't get it working. This is what I have in my migration:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return [
      queryInterface.bulkInsert('Users', [
        { username: "user1" },
        { username: "user2" }
    ])];
  },

  down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
  }
};
```

And I get this error:

```
== 20151024144833-create-conjugation: migrating =======
{ [SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error]
  name: 'SequelizeUniqueConstraintError',
  message: 'Validation error',
  errors: [],
  fields: [] }
```

There must be an easier way to do this. I've checked other SO questions, but the syntax has changed in the current version of sequelize.

**UPDATE**

Ok, I realized my mistake: I was assuming that sequelize would take care of the timestamps. This fixes the problem:

```
up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
  console.log(User);
  return [
    queryInterface.bulkInsert('Users', [
      { username: "user1", createdAt: Date.now(), updatedAt: Date.now() },
      { username: "user2", createdAt: Date.now(), updatedAt: Date.now() }
    ])
  ];
}
```

But I'm still wondering if this is the right way to seed my database. Is there a way to do it using `User.create({})`?

Comment: I had trouble with `Date.now()` and needed it to replace with `new Date()`. Using SQLite, it was not possible to query the database, since the time was saved in the wrong format (`Uncaught TypeError: date.indexOf is not a function` in `sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/data-types.js:28:14`)

Answer (score 7):

You can use next:

```
const City = sequelize.define('city', {
  name: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
  order_: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER }
});
City.sync().then(() => {
  City.create({
    name: 'Neuquen',
    order_: 0
  });
  City.create({
    name: 'General Roca',
    order_: 1
  });
});
```

Or read about "migrations" at http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/migrations/

Comment: The same code is not working for me. After rerunning my application (so that the tables already exist) the insert statements run just fine but when running the application the first time (tables are being created) only some insert statements are successful.

Answer (score 7):

```
new Date()
```

also required for mysql, i.e.

```
  return queryInterface.bulkInsert('users', [
  {
    "Forename":"A",
    "Surname": "User",
    "UserType":"1",
    "Email":"auser@gmail.com",
    "Password":"password",
    "LastLogin":0,
    "Tokens": JSON.stringify({"tokens":[]}),
    "CreatedBy": 999,
    "CreatedAt": new Date(),
    "UpdatedAt": new Date()
  }]);
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative could be use : [sequelize fixtures](https://github.com/domasx2/sequelize-fixtures) , you could init your tables with default data declared as a json file or other format.

Answer (score -1):

For a quick and easy way (without seeds or migrations) on sequelize v6:

I modified my `sequelize.sync()` call:

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

// This will create an in-memory sqlite db
const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory:', {
  logging: sequelizeLogger
});

await sequelize
  .sync({ force: true })
  .then(() => {
    // seed db
    Users.create({ username: 'user1' })
  });
```

Comment: Never use sync in production. I would actually discourage if possible because it seems you basically have to start over creating models if you want to use migrations later. It is also not what OP asked.